# How can I email the outcome of a shopping cart?

Tags: javascript, html, email, shopping-cart

Using HTML and JS, I have developed a website that has multiple items in different pages with an "add to cart" button. I can link these to appear in the "cart" page but I don't want customers to pay just yet, I want customers to be able to click a button and make an order that will be sent out to us and we can process the order. I have tried to use the email tag for HTML:

```
<a href = "mailto:delicatedesigns@gmail.com?subject = Order&body = itemsInCart
</a>
```

Is there a way to include the contents of my cart page as the body of that email? if not, is there a plug in that would work well to make this happen?

Comment: You can't rely on the user having a properly configured mail client that will respond to the `mailto:` prefix. If you want to send email from a web page you should send the data to your server and have the server generate the email. That, too, can be problematic. There are numerous questions here about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the list to the backend and setup a mail server using SMTP and then create a mail template that can be used to send the mail through the SMTP server.

Attach the list to the template and send the mail to the destination address using the SMTP server.

If you are using Java, try using the Java Mail API. This can help you set up an SMTP Server easily